# Signin display information in url

Tags: php

I have been using this login / registration code with a different website before but when adding it to my new one it just display the information in the url (`/signin?username=&password=`) I believe that everything is more or less like the old website other than css and html, `form="post" action =""` and code is copied directly from my old website.

Can someone figure out what the problem is, and maybe give a solution on how I can display login error without `die()` since it kills the rest of the page.

```
*<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <?php include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/assets/head.php"; ?>
    <title><?php echo $address; ?> - Sign In</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/navigationbar.php"; ?>

<div class="wrapper">

<div class="small-banner">
    <div id="animate-area"></div>
</div>   

    <div class="tabs" id="tabs">
        <h1>Sign In</h1>
        <div class="p">    

<?php 
    // This variable will be used to re-display the user's username to them in the 
    // login form if they fail to enter the correct password.  It is initialized here 
    // to an empty value, which will be shown if the user has not submitted the form. 
    $submitted_username = ''; 

    // This if statement checks to determine whether the login form has been submitted 
    // If it has, then the login code is run, otherwise the form is displayed 
    if(!empty($_POST)) 
    { 
        // This query retreives the user's information from the database using 
        // their username. 
        $query = " 
            SELECT 
                *
            FROM users 
                WHERE 
                username = :username 
        "; 

        // The parameter values 
        $query_params = array( 
            ':username' => $_POST['username'] 
        ); 

        try 
        { 
            // Execute the query against the database 
            $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
        } 
        catch(PDOException $ex) 
        { 
            // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage(). 
            // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code.  
            die("<div class='red'>Failed to run query: </div>" . $ex->getMessage()); 
        } 

        // This variable tells us whether the user has successfully logged in or not. 
        // We initialize it to false, assuming they have not. 
        // If we determine that they have entered the right details, then we switch it to true. 
        $login_ok = false; 

        // Retrieve the user data from the database.  If $row is false, then the username 
        // they entered is not registered. 
        $row = $stmt->fetch(); 
        if($row) 
        { 
            // Using the password submitted by the user and the salt stored in the database, 
            // we now check to see whether the passwords match by hashing the submitted password 
            // and comparing it to the hashed version already stored in the database. 
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] . $row['salt']); 
            for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++) 
            { 
                $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['salt']); 
            } 

            if($check_password === $row['password']) 
            { 
                // If they do, then we flip this to true 
                $login_ok = true; 
            } 
        } 

        // If the user logged in successfully, then we send them to the private members-only page 
        // Otherwise, we display a login failed message and show the login form again 
        if($login_ok) 
        {     
            // Here I am preparing to store the $row array into the $_SESSION by 
            // removing the salt and password values from it.  Although $_SESSION is 
            // stored on the server-side, there is no reason to store sensitive values 
            // in it unless you have to.  Thus, it is best practice to remove these 
            // sensitive values first. 
            unset($row['salt']); 
            unset($row['password']); 

            // This stores the user's data into the session at the index 'user'. 
            // We will check this index on the private members-only page to determine whether 
            // or not the user is logged in.  We can also use it to retrieve 
            // the user's details. 
            $_SESSION['user'] = $row; 

            $username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
            $last_life_update = "UPDATE users SET last_life = now() WHERE username = '$username'";
            $db->query($last_life_update);
            // Redirect the user to the private members-only page. 
            header("Location: /"); 
            die("Redirecting to: /");     
        } 
        else 
        { 
            // Tell the user they failed 
            print("<div class='red'>Login Failed.</div>"); 

            // Show them their username again so all they have to do is enter a new 
            // password.  The use of htmlentities prevents XSS attacks.  You should 
            // always use htmlentities on user submitted values before displaying them 
            // to any users (including the user that submitted them).  For more information: 
            // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSS_attack 
            $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['username'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
        } 
    } 
?>  
            <form mathod="post" action="" style="margin:20px;">
                <label for="username">Username :</label><br />
                    <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="64" id="username" placeholder="Username" class="input-long" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly');"/>
                <div class="clear-top"></div>

                <label for="password">Password :</label><br />
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" class="input-long" readonly onfocus="this.removeAttribute('readonly')   ;"/>
                <div class="clear-top"></div>

                <label><input type="checkbox" name="sport[]" value="remember" /> Remember Password</label>
                    <div class="clear-top"></div>

                <input type="submit" value="Sign In" class="btn"/><br />

                <a href="/forgot-password" class="link"><i style="color:#777f8c;">(Forgot password)</i></a>
            </form>
        </div>  
    </div>    
</div>

<div style="position:relative; clear:both;"></div>    
        <!--</body>-->
    <?php include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/footer.php"; ?>
</body>
</html>*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typo'ed 'method' in

```
   <form mathod="post" action="" style="margin:20px;">
```

The default type is GET which would result in the form parameters being in the URL.